# XML file to String using JS/VueJS (sending it to backend server)

Tags: xml, string, vue.js

I need to convert an uploaded .xml file to String and send it to the back-end server. I need to preserve the original "look", in other words - there is for example: `<process.end.date>20100131</process.end.date>` so the tags must remain and sent it like that. How can I convert the file?

***uploadXML.vue***

```
<template>
  <fieldset class="buttons">
    <span class="logInBTN" v-on:click="send(xml)">Send</span>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <div class="mainContainer">
    <table border="0px">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Upload file: </label>
          <input id="fileInput" type="file" @change="handleUpload" accept=".xml"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
  import config from '../main.js'

  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        xml: ''
      }
    },
    methods:{
      send(xml){
        console.log("Result1:\n\n" + this.xml);
        const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'manualReceive'
        this.submit('post',url, xml);
      },
      submit(requestType, url, submitData) {
        this.$http[requestType](url, submitData)
          .then(response => {
          console.log("manualReceive " + response.data);
        if(response.data == true)
          alert('Successful Sent!');
        else
          alert('Problem with sending message!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log('error:' + error);
      });
      },
      handleUpload: function(){
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
          this.xml = reader.result;
          console.log("Result:\n\n" + this.xml);
        });
        this.xml = reader.readAsText(file);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

***Update:***
I realized that the xml is in string format. Now I know what the problem is - when I write `console.log("Result1:\n\n" + this.xml);` in send(xml) function it's undefined. While `console.log("Result:\n\n" + this.xml);` works fine
How can I fix this?

***Update2:***

```
<script>
  import config from '../main.js'

  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        xml: ''
      }
    },
    methods:{
      send(){
        /*console.log("Result2:\n\n" + this.xml);*/
        const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'manualReceive'
        this.submit('post',
          url,
          this.xml
        );
      },
      submit(requestType, url, submitData) {
        this.$http[requestType](url, submitData)
          .then(response => {
          console.log("manualReceive " + response.data);
        if(response.data == true)
          alert('Успешно изпратено съобщение към CDCO!');
        else
          alert('Проблем при изпращането на съобщението!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log('error:' + error);
      });
      },
      handleUpload: function(){
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var self = this;
        reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
          self.xml = reader.result;
          /*console.log("Result1:\n\n" + self.xml);*/
        });
        reader.readAsText(file);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `reader.result` already has string type because file was read with `readAsText`method. So you can send use `this.xml` and send its content to server.

Comment: I updated my initial first post. I need this.xml is undefined in send(xml) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need pass `xml` to `send` function because your `xml` string is property of Vue instance. Change `send` function to this:

```
send(){
    const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'manualReceive'
    this.submit('post',url, this.xml);
}
```

And in template:

```
<span class="logInBTN" v-on:click="send">Send</span>
```

**UPDATE**

Also you don't need to assign `this.xml` in this line:

```
this.xml = reader.readAsText(file);
```

Just use:

```
reader.readAsText(file);
```

**UPDATE 2**

You use `function` word in function declaration in "load" event so `this` variable is FileReader.
You should store correct `this` or use arrow functions:

```
var self = this;
reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
      self.xml = reader.result;
      console.log("Result:\n\n" + self.xml);
    });
```

Then `this.xml` will work in send function.

Comment: But "console.log("Result1:\n\n" + this.xml); in send()", this.xml is undefined

Comment: @Decrux see Update 2 in my answer

Comment: Ahhh right, thanks for the explanation it was very helpful. Meanwhile even if I don't set self.xml, this.xml will work here " this.submit('post',url, this.xml); " right?

Comment: @Decrux yes, but will be empty if you don’t set it

Comment: Ok self.this will stay :)

Comment: we just need store `this` to access its props in anonymous functions declared with `function`. In vue methods you can use `this` directly. I think you can mark answer as correct :)

Comment: Can you please just see in the first post I updated the code. This will work correctly right?

Comment: @Decrux yep, it will